# Saving kafka consumer messages to database

Tags: mysql, streaming, apache-spark, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on making a streaming database for stream analytic. Can anybody give me the step wise code to update the Kafka message in database like mySQL or Hive to use it for analytic?

I setup my Zookeeper and Kafka but, not able to save messages to any persistent Database to use it for Reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Spark works well with Kafka. See this [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html).
Here is a Kafka consumer for spark
And here is an [excellent tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/) on getting them to work together.

Once you got Kafka + Spark working together,  then you can store the messages into data store.  Spark & Cassandra is a popular combination.  See these tutorials for reference.

http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-apache-spark-and-cassandra/

http://helenaedelson.com/?p=991

Comment: Request you to help me with step by step guide as I tried it on my own without luck. I want to connect to transaction database at one side and other side want to store data in OLAP database. e.g. I want to pass realtime transaction to data warehouse for reporting.

Comment: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started. [LinkedIn's Kafka to HDFS pipeline](https://github.com/linkedin/camus)